# Create a fetch for "buy" on specific DEX having pairAddress - web3.py

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

old developer re-learning. I'm trying to build a bot for fetching and returning buys from DEXes having the exact pair fetched. I'm struggling to understand what should I do exactly to fetch the single event for transfer which brings WBNB (WETH) inside the LP Contract.

My goal is to print a variable where i can fetch:

- Buyer Address (receiver of the tokens)
- Amount of tokens received
- Amount spent (probably in WBNB)

I assume the logic would be applicable for any EVM with the exact node for the chain.

What I did since now:

```
#Library Imports
from web3 import Web3
import web3
import json

#.env
node_url_eth = '#myNode'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url_eth))

#TokenToFetchPair
token_a = '0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82' #token address
token_b = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c' #WBNB address
#toChecksum
checksum_token_a = Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_a)
checksum_token_b = Web3.toChecksumAddress(token_b)

#PCS/Token Variables
PCS_FACTORY_ABI = '#very long abi'
PCS_FACTORY_ADDRESS="0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73"
PCS_FACTORY_ADDRESS = Web3.toChecksumAddress(PCS_FACTORY_ADDRESS)
standard_abi = '#commonAbiForTokens'
cakePair_abi = '#AbiCakePair'

#Fetching
TokenContract = web3.eth.contract(address=checksum_token_a, abi=standard_abi)
PCS_FACTORY_CONTRACT = web3.eth.contract(address=PCS_FACTORY_ADDRESS, abi=PCS_FACTORY_ABI)

getTokenName = TokenContract.functions.name().call()
getTokenSymbol = TokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
fetchedPair = PCS_FACTORY_CONTRACT.functions.getPair(checksum_token_a, checksum_token_b).call()

print(getTokenName, getTokenSymbol, fetchedPair)


#FilterEvents(Code I found)
filter = web3.eth.filter({
        "topic0": '0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822', #topic for Swap inside LPAddress
    "fromBlock": 26218413,
    "toBlock": "latest",
    "address": fetchedPair,

    })

print(filter.get_all_entries())
```

And so the output i get is this:

```
[AttributeDict({'address': '0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0', 'topics': [HexBytes('0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1')], 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000016f25b1b4b6795800b9526000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004cb94fd8206ab16966e8', 'blockNumber': 26215464, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x1028b3a9af98607134e1e54235dcd0e100f320c930d5dec45c8f743f5e670742'), 'transactionIndex': 10, 'blockHash': HexBytes('0xc0dc8b3fc4bbfd97fe16be2bf61068384da5818a73dd82c737262222d60672b0'), 'logIndex': 80, 'removed': False})
```

Ideally I'll have just one output at the time, but what i get is:

```
[AttributeDict({'address': '0x87D7fd8c446Cb5D3da3CA23f429e7b7504d1931C', 'topics': [HexBytes('0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1')], 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000907b8c58c16d28000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001eb991a56c6bd82f8', 'blockNumber': 26237428, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xde30935977312dae766cba3bc34527746042d38fcd7518f8af697d90aeb97965'), 'transactionIndex': 17, 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x83b1359ce6024fda05a1456f727ddc26c33990a6fa193b61aef114de4ea1c459'), 'logIndex': 42, 'removed': False}), AttributeDict({'address': '0x87D7fd8c446Cb5D3da3CA23f429e7b7504d1931C', 'topics': [HexBytes('0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822'), HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000010ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e'), HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000010ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e')], 'data': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012bad655142500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003f99c25c1590a5', 'blockNumber': 26237428, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xde30935977312dae766cba3bc34527746042d38fcd7518f8af697d90aeb97965'), 'transactionIndex': 17, 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x83b1359ce6024fda05a1456f727ddc26c33990a6fa193b61aef114de4ea1c459'), 'logIndex': 43, 'removed': False}), AttributeDict({'address': '0x87D7fd8c446Cb5D3da3CA23f429e7b7504d1931C', 'topics': [HexBytes('0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1')], 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000921011bfcd2785000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e64afcf83fd9b1ee', 'blockNumber': 26237470, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x16d95898e57006bf7e0d7dbec48fef139778ec7f5ea3afbdf0e3d1a4937fd878'), 'transactionIndex': 45, 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x5a4524aaf413650ad1f81a1e257f200f1c5d398806f71d1c2fe8fffe89cace49'), 'logIndex': 122, 'removed': False}), AttributeDict({'address': '0x87D7fd8c446Cb5D3da3CA23f429e7b7504d1931C', 'topics': [HexBytes('0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822'), HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000010ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e'), HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000231d9e7181e8479a8b40930961e93e7ed798542c')], 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019485670bba5d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054e1d5e86e3d10a', 'blockNumber': 26237470, 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x16d95898e57006bf7e0d7dbec48fef139778ec7f5ea3afbdf0e3d1a4937fd878'), 'transactionIndex': 45, 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x5a4524aaf413650ad1f81a1e257f200f1c5d398806f71d1c2fe8fffe89cace49'), 'logIndex': 123, 'removed': False})]
```

which just this is only 2 fetches.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to fetch only one output at time? (Ideally when it's created)
2. What's the most efficient way to fetch buys from a DEX without using thousands of calls each minute?
3. Is somewhere a code I can review with explanation on how to accomplish this?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: [Here is an example for printing out live trades as they happen on Uniswap v2 compatible DEX](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/index.html).

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thank you so much, this will for sure help a lot!